# PHP syntax error using const array via switch case. Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, syntax

I can't understand why the follow code is marked as Syntax error expression by Netbeans. Anyway this code Works correctly into my project and it is defined into a class.

Thanks!

```
...        
const UPDATE_LISTINI = array(
    "TABLE_NAME" => "update_listini",
     "TABLE_LOW_FILE_NAME" => "update_listini",
     "TABLE_FILE_REGEX" => "update_listini_*",
     "TABLE_FILE_NOT_REGEX" => "_[0-9]*$",
     "TABLE_FILE_FORMAT" => null,
     "TABLE_FILE_SEPARATOR" => null,
     "COLUMN_COUNT" => 4,
     "INDEX_OF" => array(
    "DATA" => 0,
     "USER" => 1,
     "GRUPPO" => 2,
     ),
    );

    const SELECT = "SELECT ";
    const FROM = " FROM ";

...   

    public function sql_getQuery_select_LastUpdate($tablename, $fields){
    switch ($tablename){
    case self::UPDATE_LISTINI['TABLE_NAME'] : return self::SELECT."MAX(".$fields.") ".self::FROM.self::UPDATE_LISTINI['TABLE_NAME'];
    case self::UPDATE_PROMO['TABLE_NAME'] : return self::SELECT."MAX(".$fields.") ".self::FROM.self::UPDATE_PROMO['TABLE_NAME'];
    case self::UPDATE_SCONTI['TABLE_NAME'] : return self::SELECT."MAX(".$fields.") ".self::FROM.self::UPDATE_SCONTI['TABLE_NAME'];

    }
    } 
...
```

Comment: *marked as Syntax error* Do you have a more precise error message ? Or does Netbeans say: `Syntax error line x - xx` ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare constants as any type of language construct. It has to be a **static value** only.

[As of PHP 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php), you can use some scalars on your declaration

> It is now possible to provide a scalar expression involving numeric and string literals and/or constants in contexts where PHP previously expected a static value, such as constant and property declarations and default function arguments.

Comment: ok I'm agree. Why the script works fine into my project., thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can  do like this code

```
    <?php

class CmsAdminMenuHelper {
    const ADMIN_MENU_USERS = 1;
    const ADMIN_MENU_USERS_NAME = 'Users';
    const ADMIN_MENU_CATEGORIES = 2;
    const ADMIN_MENU_CATEGORIES_NAME = 'Categories';
    const ADMIN_MENU_PRODUCTS = 3;
    const ADMIN_MENU_PRODUCTS_NAME = 'Products';
    const ADMIN_MENU_STATIC_PAGES = 4;
    const ADMIN_MENU_STATIC_PAGES_NAME = 'Static Pages';
    const ADMIN_MENU_ADMINSTRATORS = 5;
    const ADMIN_MENU_ADMINISTRATORS_NAME = 'Administrators';
    const ADMIN_MENU_EMAIL_TRACING = 6;
    const ADMIN_MENU_EMAIL_TRACING_NAME = 'Email Tracking';
    public static  $ADMIN_MENU_ARRAY =array(
            self::ADMIN_MENU_USERS => self::ADMIN_MENU_USERS_NAME,
            self::ADMIN_MENU_CATEGORIES => self::ADMIN_MENU_CATEGORIES_NAME,
            self::ADMIN_MENU_PRODUCTS => self::ADMIN_MENU_PRODUCTS_NAME,
            self::ADMIN_MENU_STATIC_PAGES =>self::ADMIN_MENU_STATIC_PAGES_NAME,
            self::ADMIN_MENU_ADMINSTRATORS => self::ADMIN_MENU_ADMINISTRATORS_NAME,
            self::ADMIN_MENU_EMAIL_TRACING => self::ADMIN_MENU_EMAIL_TRACING_NAME,
    );
    public static $SUPER_ADMIN_EDIT_VIEW_REMOVE_ARRAY =  array(
            'view'=>true,
            'edit'=>true,
            'remove'=>true      
        );
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your code is going to help the OP have a better understanding of your answer and increase the value of you answer for later reference by other users

Comment: Thanks so much to everybody! I'm going to perform this suggest as soon as possible into my project :)